# How can I get the return code for a command which ran via ssh and not the ssh command itself?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script in which one of the first steps is to check for the presence of a file in a remote host and whether it is executable or not. This sounds like a job for the `test` command, but I'd have to prefix it with `ssh`. Something like this:

```
$(ssh user@box 'test -x /path/thefile >/dev/null 2>&1; $?')
```

Except the above doesn't seem to be working to return to me whether the remote file exists and is executable...how would I do this?

Comment: Unless there is an `ssh` error (in which case, the exit code is 255), the exit code of `ssh` *is* the exit code of the remote process. You simply aren't checking for the exit code; you're capturing standard output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `$()` syntax, you are getting the output of the command, and not the result code.  You can just do:

```
if ssh user@box 'test -x /path/thefile'; then
  echo "It exists"
fi
```